# What is the easiest way to get the AAD application ID of MSI enabled app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

I have a App service deployed with MSI enabled (with system assigned identity). This App service will use MSI to retrieve access token to an AAD protected web API. The web API will retrieve the appid from the token and check the appid against a pre-configured white list, if the appid is not in white list, the access is denied.

So to allow the MSI enabled app service to access the Web API, I need to know the application id of MSI app service and add it to the white list.

I know I can run following powershell script in my app service debug console to retrieve the token and get the appid by decoding the token.

```
$apiVersion = "2017-09-01"
$resourceURI = "<resource uri of AAD protected Web API>"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:MSI_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=$apiVersion"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"Secret"="$env:MSI_SECRET"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

But I am wondering if there is easier way to get the appid of MSI app service without retrieving a token.

Comment: Why do you need to manually check the app_id from code ? you should assign your MSI to WebApi then you're sure only trusted consumer can call your webapi

Comment: Thanks Thomas, any doc I can refer to?

Comment: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: Thanks Nancy, your approach works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId xxxx).ApplicationId`, the object ID is easy to find when you check it on the web app portal.

[image]

[image]

You also could search the application in the **Enterprise applications** by the application ID.
[image]